# Element of a set contained in another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have one very elementary but puzzling question.

We know the rule that *set* can also be an *object*, i. e. an element of another set. And with this we get somewhat more complicated theory than dealing with sets that are not containing anothers sets.

So, for example, $\{1, 2\} \in \{\{1, 2\}, 3\}$ but $\{1, 2\} \not\subset \{\{1, 2\}, 3\}$ because $1, 2$ are not elements of $\{\{1, 2\}, 3\}$. But obviously $1, 2$ are connected with and contained (in some weird way) in $\{\{1, 2\}, 3\}$. Is there a symbol for this?

In other words, if a set $S$ contains a set $s$ with element $a$, than $a$ is not element of $S$ but obviously is in "borders" of $S$. Is there a mathematical term to describe this relation?

I also view sets as boxes so this perfectly makes sense but I wonder if there is a proper term for "boxing the box".

Thanks.

Comment: You want the transitive closure of $\in$.

Comment: Can you please bring more details?

Comment: You wanna *flattern* a set one level at a time?